# Unity download and hide file on Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, download, mono

I'm working in Unity 5.6.0 at a system for android, what at first launch is downloading some files (a .txt and 4 .mp4).

After this my app will use those files. At second launch, app will load files, not downloading.

Saving files is made by get `Byte[]` from server and `File.WriteAllBytes` after.
My problem is, that I don't want to give user any access to those files.

How can I save files in a game directory and hide them from user?

Comment: To hide a file you will need to encrypt the file and save it without using a file extension.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly hide the files from the user but you can try to encrypt them using the [`Crypto`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto(v=vs.111).aspx) class.

```
class Test
{
    private static Crypto m_Crypto = null;
    static Test()
    {
        m_Crypto = new Crypto("SOME_PASSWORD_HERE", "SOME_SALT_HERE");
    }

    public static void Write(string value)
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath,
                           m_Crypto.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value)));
    }
}
```

If you use `Appication.persistentDataPath` then the data will be stored in the App Data for your app on Android.

Comment: Thx for answer. I will give a try.

Comment: No problem. Remember that if the user clears app data then it will remove this file. If you feel it solves your question then please accept the answer.